# How can I change the length of the NavigationViewItem selection underline to match the item content text in a WinUI3 app?

Tags: navigationview, winui-3

I have not seen an example or documentation for a property that lets me change the length of a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem blue selector line to be the length of the content text.  The blue selector is very short by default.  Here is a code snippet:

```
        <NavigationView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded"
                        ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked"
                        BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested"
                        IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                        IsBackEnabled="false"
                        PaneDisplayMode="Top">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Tag="basics"  Content="Window Basics"></NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Tag="presenters" Content="Presenters"></NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Tag="configs" Content="Window Configurations"></NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Tag="titlebar" Content="TitleBar"></NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </NavigationView>
```

Is there a property that lets me adjust the selector length or automatically stretches it to fit the content?  For example, in the xaml snippet above, I would like the selection line to fit the length of the text "Window Basics" when the first item is selected.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Even the Microsoft samples I've seen (including the Xaml Controls Gallery demo) have the short underlining.

Thanks very much for any assistance.

- Robert

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that a simple UWP app with NavigationView *does* underline the NavigationViewItem contents correctly.  That app is using Microsoft.UI.xaml 2.5.

So it may be that the WinUI app I am writing, using Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK 1.0 has a bug.

Comment: I think in WinUI 3 the selected NavigationViewItem is not underlined; instead, there is a line on the left.